# Custom Territory management

Tags: territory, management

what data model we need to pick when implementing Custom Territory Management solution with Collaborative forecasting ?

We do not want to use Customizable forecasting so we have to turn off Standard Territory Management.

how we can control access for records when managing public Groups in the Hierarchy ?

Please suggest.

Thanks